# "Unable to autoload constant" using rspec but not rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've this file which I would like to test.

`app/workers/station/http.rb`

```
module Worker
  module Station
    class HTTP
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

This is my spec file.

`spec/workers/station/http_spec.rb`

```
describe Worker::Station::HTTP do
  it "should do something"  do
  end 
end
```

The problem now is that I'm getting the following error when running the spec file using rspec.

`rspec spec/workers/station/http_spec.rb`

```
/Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:464:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Station::HTTP, expected app/workers/station/http.rb to define it (LoadError)
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  from spec/workers/station/http_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

The strange thing is that everyting works in the console.

`$ rails c
    [1] pry(main)> Worker::Station::HTTP
    => Worker::Station::HTTP`

Why is this happening using rspec and not in rails and how would I fix it?

I'm using

- rails (4.0.4)
- rspec (2.14.1)

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you figure out how to fix this?

Comment: The app/workers path is not being autoloaded by rspec because it is not standard rails layout, you can add an autoload line to your spec_helper or require the file in the spec directly!

Comment: @jfornoff please insert your comment as an answer. this will help other ppl encountering this problem. thanks for the help!

Comment: Good point, thanks

Answer (score 3):

As jfornoff suggests you could add a require statement to the spec with a statement something like the following:

`require "app/workers/station/http"`

But if you are using the Spring Rails application preloader and the above doesn't resolve the problem, you could also check to see if Spring needs to be restarted. You can test running the spec without using Spring as follows:

`bundle exec rspec spec/workers/station/http_spec.rb`

... or ...

```
spring stop # or bin/spring stop
rspec spec/workers/station/http_spec.rb
```

Comment: `spring stop` helped me!

Answer (score 1):

The `app/workers` path is not being autoloaded by rspec because it is not standard rails layout, you can add an autoload line to your spec_helper or require the file in the spec directly!

Answer (score 0):

## Note: If solutions above/below do not work for you.

---

In Rails 4.1 and 4.2 I got similar error while trying to run the following command

```
$ spring rspec spec/classes/email_parser/email_provider_spec.rb:163
```

even tried

```
$ rspec spec/classes/email_parser/email_provider_spec.rb:163
```

---

### Unable to autoload constant Account::Onboarding

```
Called from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Account::Onboarding, expected /Users/john/Projects/Core/app/models/account/onboarding.rb to define it (LoadError)
        from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
        from /Users/john/Projects/Core/app/models/account.rb:9:in `<class:Account>'
        from /Users/john/Projects/Core/app/models/account.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

### Cause

Turns out, I recently restarted my Mac and forgot to start the PG server. Not finding the PG server to respond to port `5432`, the app seems to be crashing with logs that do not make any sense.

### Solution that worked for me

I started the PG server.

```
# For Mac
$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@11 start 

# For Linux
$ sudo service postgresql start
```